# Material and Texture to Achieve an appearance

Tags: texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine

How to do this in Blender render:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Every_Material_Known_to_Man/Light_Effects

Settings are there but I couldn't recreated it because some of them were replaced with new ones.

I need B.render because I'm using halo material specific in the scene.
Thanks

I want to look like this

[image]

EDIT:
Still need a bit of tweak. How to get this white color on top of the wave ?
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13451287/bsphere.blend
[image]

Comment: It would be useful for you to place an image of your work with the question.  Yes the manual you mentioned is not fresh.  Please create a sphere with lots of vertices and add a displacement modifier with a noise texture, to achieve a bumpy shape.  Show the image of your work in the question so we can help with you from there.  Your work need not be perfect but it allows quicker help if you can provide the image.  If you do  not understand those two suggestion please say so in a comment.  The lights simple, better or advanced can come later.

Comment: I don't know how to make this transparent water surface annd below blue. On the page there was some NOR variable. This is not anymore in 2.75. Probably IOR. Btw, will there be integrated in BR material nodes as in Cycles? Then would be easier to make this complex material.

Comment: Very nice. So your question is now how do I achieve a certain color effect?  I need a few moments

Comment: On the page there were 3 textures involved on material in the description

Comment: Please show a render with transparency if that is a concern.  Please show the Text Mapping Coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Here is a modest sloppy facsimile at the end of the post.

You must adjust to taste and artistry.
I am trying to show a technique and you can run free from there.
I am not using the exact same settings as the old manual.
I am not using Fresnel.

Blender Render. Please note there are no lights in the image below.
Shadeless Material and Texture Mapping Coordinates [Normal] with an Radial Gradiant Image.

Here is a material setting
Note the shadeless and transparency

[image]

Here is a texture setting. Note the coordinates are [Normal].  The circular image with transparency. The color ramp to threshold color.

[image]

Note that the alpha is modified.

[image]

Note the circular image which is transparent in middle. 
This can be created in GIMP or Blender.  The color ramp modifies the intensity of this image.  Modify all to suit your tastes.

[image]

Some experiments to show some use of the color ramp.

[image]

Below we see transparency.  The Mapping Coordinates is (Geometric Surface) [Normal].  Exaggerated white colors.
Note the color ramp with the Red Marker.  You may change that to blue.
[image]
Please experiment and know my circular image could be simplified by you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll get on it. Btw, I'm creating a larger scene. I don't know how to make some animation with another procedural texture. Could you look into it when I'll post it ?

Comment: Please progress with this work or discard. Mark the answer positive or negative.   Questions should have a single focus.  Lets be present.

Comment: I did. Thank you. I edited first post. Still the image needs some white color on top.